# Disable Anchor tag and on mouse hover show title-msg why it's disabled

Tags: html, css

I want to disable Anchor tag and on mouse hover show a title, why it's disabled?

```
<a href="domain.xyz" title="why it's disabled">sample domain</a>
```

tried below:

```
.disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: default !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

*but mouse-hover is not working.*

Any pointers how to do this using css ?

Comment: if you disable `pointer-events`, the tooltip won't show. You have to use a mix of CSS/Javascript: for example disable click by JS and remove the `pointer-events` rule.

Comment: A link disabled, shouldn't be a link but just simple text. You might need to rethink your design. Inspecting the code would reveal the `href` and people could potentially still navigate to the url. You might need to do more than just "disable" the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `:after` element appear with the `content: attr(title)` to display the reason.

```css
a.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.disabled:hover::after {
 content: attr(title);
 padding-left: 10px;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="disabled" title="Unavailable now" onclick="return false">Click here</a>
```

Comment: here we are not blocking user to do action, only cursor-symbol is changing

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code. This tricks the browser behavior so first it's applying :active styles.

```
.disabled-icon:active, .disabled-icon:active:focus, .disabled-icon:active:hover, .disabled-icon:hover:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```